# differentiating between empty textnode and textnode with whitespaces

Tags: java, regex, whitespace, text-normalization

While validating an xml file, I want to logg any text-node with empty content. A newline \n is also considered a texnode but it is not what I want to aprove. In the following code:
'parent' has two textnodes of content '\n' that are not interesting to me. The content of 'elem1' is  '\n\n', which is an error and must be reported. 'elem2' has a valid content. Content of 'books' is empty and must be reported.

In my first try I searched each text-node for [\n\t\r] and would ignore them. But this way I would also ignore elem1 which should have been reported as error.

What is the point I am doing wrong? (notice: I have to solve this issue without xsd-validation)

Update 1): I have added more \n between the elements. Now the first 'parent' node has 5 textnodes with content: \n

```
<root>

    <parent>

        <elem1>

        </elem1> 

        <elem2>good content of el2</elem2>

        <elem3> half so good
               contentof el3</elem3>
    </parent>
    
    <parent>
        <elem1>
        </elem1> 

        <elem2>good content</elem2>
        <elem3>good</elem3>

        <elem4></elem4>

    </parent>

    <book></book>
    

</root>
```

Update 2) for more clearness: wenn a caller calls say validate("//parent/*"),   I gather all nodes of this given path and get a nodelist returned. Then I  start the validation for each node and its children.

```
Nodelist result = xpathinstance.validate(path, currentNode, XPathConstants.NODESET)

for (int n = 0; n < result.getLength(); n++) {

            validateThereAreNoGaps(result.item(n));
        }
```

Wenn I arive on the first 'parent'-element it shows 7 children (after update of example). Each \n between the element-tags is considered a text-node.

As a next solution I am now trying to replace all \n with "" to get rid of them...

Comment: If I read you correctly you want to find all text nodes that contain only whitespace, but ignore all of those that contain exactly 1 newline, right?

Comment: @Joachim Sauer Not exactly one. The author of the xml file might have inserted several new lines between the elements for readability purpose.

Comment: @Mandy8055 using a parser would expect a model definition for the document, which I never use in my validation code.

Comment: But you say that `elem1` is an error, which is exactly that: two newlines, why is that an error when adding whitespace for readability is ok?

Comment: @Joachim the rule I am validating says: nodes in path //parent/* are expected not to be empty but filled at least with a 'xyz'.

Comment: In my answer I have addressed that @saab.Please see once.Also please drop a comment if you need something else.

Comment: @Mandy8055 I search for alle nodes with the given path and get a nodelist back. Then I validate each node in the list and its children for their contents. I have 'nodes' instead of strings, so that I can not apply the regular expression you have suggested. I will update my description.

Comment: @Mandy8055 finally I found a way. How do you think about this: the text nodes inside elem1, elem2, and elem3 have neigther a next sibling nor a previous sibling. But a text-node inside the 'parent' (e.g.  \n ) has a next sibling which is <elem1>. The last text node of 'parent' (which is also  \n )  has only a previous sibling but no next silbing.

Comment: Does the XML format is going to be same always? If yes then your way is worth appreciating =)

Comment: unfortunately it was not a correct solution. I added another elem4 which is empty and should be logged as error. But it is being ignored for \n before and after the <elem4>. I must have misunderstood the meaning of sibling...

Answer (score 0):

Here's a short expression that might help you:

```
<(\w+?>)[^\S]*<\/\1
```

This will select any text node that is empty.

If you don't want to select the tags, just use this:

```
<(?<=(\w+?>))[^\S]*(?=<\/\1)
```

However this second one cannot identify:

```
<books></books>
```

for example, but  in  that case I  suggest simply using:

```
><
```

as your expression to find those seperately.